# Multiple database contexts with Npgsql causing migration failure

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8 web app, and am using Entity Framework with Npgsql 8.0.1.

I am initialising multiple database contexts using the `NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder` as [described here](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html).

Program.cs

```csharp
//DbContext 1
var applicationDataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ApplicationConnection"]);
await using var applicationDataSource = applicationDataSourceBuilder.Build();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(applicationDataSource);
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(builder.Environment.IsDevelopment());
    });

//DbContext 2
var otherDataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:OtherConnection"]);
otherDataSourceBuilder.UseNetTopologySuite();
await using var otherDataSource = otherDataSourceBuilder.Build();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<OtherDbContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(otherDataSource);
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(builder.Environment.IsDevelopment());
    });
```

This works fine from what I can tell when actually running the app (but maybe there are some nasties lurking which I'm unaware of at this point!), but if I attempt any migrations, such as running `Update-Database -Context ApplicationDbContext` the following error is thrown.

> An error occurred using the connection to database 'devapps' on server
> 'tcp://localhost:5432'.
>
> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>
> Object name: 'Npgsql.PoolingDataSource'.

If I switch the `ApplicationDbContext` to use this style of initialization (i.e. without using the `NpggqlDataSourceBuilder`)

```csharp
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql("name=ConnectionStrings:ApplicationConnection");
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(builder.Environment.IsDevelopment());
    });
```

It works fine, but I was under the impression from the docs that using the `NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder` was the recommended way of doing things.

I've come to the conclusion I must be fundamentally mis-understanding the proper way to initialize multiple database contexts with Npgsql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the comments by [@Shay Rojansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640325/shay-rojansky) (owner of Npgsql) your can (should?) use `NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder` in this case.

The problem you are experiencing is caused by the following:

- [using declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using) will dispose the created datasource at the end of the [generated `Program.<Main>$` method for top-level statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements#semantics)
- EF Core tools get needed setup to perform operations with some dirty magic (currently they invoke `Program.<Main>$` to build the host but prevent the host from running by throwing exception via [`DiagnosticListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/diagnosticsource-diagnosticlistener) instrumentation) resulting in the exit from the scope containing the datasource and as result datasource disposal.

Available options (at least I know/can think of):

- By miles the easiest option would be to just remove the `using`'s:

  ```
  var applicationDataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ApplicationConnection"]);
  var applicationDataSource = applicationDataSourceBuilder.Build();
  // use applicationDataSource
  // ...
  var otherDataSource = otherDataSourceBuilder.Build();
  // use otherDataSource
  ```
- Add [`IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) to the project which will handle things differently for design time.
- Expand the `using` into `try`-`finally` and dispose in finally only if [`EF.IsDesignTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.isdesigntime?view=efcore-7.0) is `false`.

Comment: FWIW [these EFCore.PG docs](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html) are indeed outdated, they need to show an example with a data source. And removing the await is probably the right solution here.

Comment: @ShayRojansky thank you for the information! I assumed that dataSource was handled somehow internally in the registration. Then I need to fix the answer. But not today since it's too late for me.

Comment: Removing the `await using` has indeed fixed the migrations and allows me to still use the NpsqlDataSourceBuilder

Comment: @RobQuincey updated the answer with some explanations and options.