# Avoid external call for configuration when integraiton testing with WebApplication.CreateBuilder()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I'm implementing an Azure Container App that relies on a call with Dapr to get values from a Key Vault. This call is executed during application startup, but `new DaprClientBuilder().Build()` naturally fails when running in a `WebApplicationFactory`. I want to avoid this call when integration testing with `WebApplicationFactory`.
I've tried numerous approaches but I'm stuck getting to a point where I can omit that external call during startup.

`Program.cs` goes like this

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddApplication();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder);
builder.Services.AddPresentation(builder);

builder.Configuration.AddDaprSecretStore("secrets", new DaprClientBuilder().Build());

var app = builder.Build();
```

Before when we had a `Program` and a `Startup` (before `WebApplication.CreateBuilder()`) it was easier to tap in the startup with `WebApplicationFactory` because host build and application build was split. It simply meant creating a new host in the factory, thus omitting the external calls, overriding `ConfigreAppConfiguration()` and adding test configuration here. But this approach is now invalid since host build up and application buildup is mixed in `Program.cs`. Therefore I cannot use `.UseStartup<Program>()`.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Guard the call to `AddDaprSecretStore()` behind an if statement that checks an environment variable (or the configuration built so-far) for whether the code is running in Azure or not? I do a similar thing for Azure Key Vault.

Comment: Thanks for replying, appreciated! I could do that, but i really dont like environmentspecific code in Startup. I've always resorted to the test being responsible for removing/adding parts instead of polluting Startup.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK not much can be done here. If I remember correctly then `WebApplicationFactory` uses some dirty magic (similar to one briefly [described here for EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77627595/2501279)) to perform app setup which requires everything before `builder.Build()` to be executed.

You need to either migrate back to [the generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-8.0) (the one with `Startup`'s files, note that in theory you should be able to use [environment specific `Startup`'s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#startup-class-conventions) with it) or perform custom initialization logic based on environment. For example (you can move it to some neatly encapsulated extension/`Program` method):

```
if (!builder.Environment.IsEnvironment("TEST"))
{
    builder.Configuration.AddDaprSecretStore("secrets", new DaprClientBuilder().Build());
}
```

And in the test:

```
var webApplicationFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
webApplicationFactory = webApplicationFactory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
{
    // ...
    builder.UseEnvironment("Test");
});

// use webApplicationFactory
```

Or via custom application factory:

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // ...
        builder.UseEnvironment("Test");
    }
}
```